# Enable interface / set IP from C++ (with Qt) and Linux

Tags: c++, qt, interface, ip, netmask

I need to bring an interface up/down from C++ running on Linux, and set the IP/netmask  (And I use Qt in case that helps).

I need to create the equivalent capability of the ifconfig command from within c++.  Is there an interface/library available to help me do this?

Comment: The source code for `ifconfig` is available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to do it through ioctls: /usr/include/linux/sockios.h
Welcome to Linux!